# Are there any lightweight third-party implementations for working with Google Adsense in .NET?

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client, adsense-api

I don't want my application to have any unneeded dependencies, log4net being one such dependency. As such, are there any thin third-party libraries or will I need to write my own?

Also, for those of you who need to have the "Why?" question answered, it comes down to the fact that I find 100k of binary code to conditionally write a single line of text to a file (my use case) to be a bit on the excessive side.

Comment: I'm in a similar position with the amount of dependencies for using the .NET Client Library. I know nuget deals with it but it becomes a problem on legacy products with a large dependency tree of projects and solutions depending on one project that depends on your project using the API and then forces these dependencies on them. nuget pulls down copies of packages for each solution also.

Also have to ensure all the dependent assemblies are included in the final install package. It at least doubles the number of assemblies just for a couple of Google API calls I need to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about third party products but you could resort to using the raw HTTP REST API.

https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/v4.1/ (this is for the AdSense Host API)

Google's documentation tends to hide it and they discourage using it in many places, mainly for security reasons they claim (ease of making mistakes with the JSON Web Tokens).

Comment: I think I'm going this route. I might borrow their signing code since it's under an Apache license to save the effort of implementing it.